# Hibernate. Difficulties with entity uniqueness

Tags: spring, hibernate

Have an oracle stored procedure (with REF_CURSOR), which is being called by

`entityManager.createStoredProcedure(name, EntityClass.class)`

The entity is basically a table with a dumb design, which didn't really bother with having a unique field, so the data looks like this:

```
field1 const1 const2 value1
field1 const1 const2 value2
field1 const1 const2 value3
```

The four field is just an example, the real case is 10+ fields, and there is more than one procedure of such sort, from which I need to pull data.

I do see that making an `@IdClass` with spamming all of the fields is a possibility,
I feel that having an `@Entity` + `@SqlResultSetMapping(classes = @ConstructorResult(...))` to have less impact on my today's headache.

But still, want to make something decent out of this.

One thing I thought I could squish in, is a `uuid` column to have all of the fields as unique. But that didn't go well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe *Example 622. Calling an Oracle REF_CURSOR stored procedure using JPA* from the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-sp) will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I'm already thinking of doing it through ResultSet, but wanted something more `clean`.